# Corrupted double linked-list for opencv library

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Hi I've written this simple program

Main.cpp

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> PD_Classifier_VEC;
#define Folder_Address ""
int Main()
{
        int overall_counter=0;

        for(int j = 0 ; j < 600 ; j++)
          {
               QString address = Folder_Address + QString::number(overall_counter++) +".jpg";
               cv::Mat image = cv::imread(address.toUtf8().constData(),0);
               PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(image);
               PD();
          }
}
```

PD Function

```
void PD()
{
            static int Total_Frame_Number=0;
            Total_Frame_Number++;
            cv::Mat Point_MAT = cv::Mat(PD_Classifier_VEC[0].size(),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(0)); 

   ....//Some Calculation //

       PD_Classifier_VEC[0].release();
       PD_Classifier_VEC.erase(PD_Classifier_VEC.begin());

}
```

this code works fine till j=56, after that Qt display this error and quits !!!

```
*** Error in `/home/parsa/QtProjects/QtVLPR/QtVLPR': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000dcf880 ***
```

I ran the code in debugger mode and added this if statement code to PD() Function:

```
void PD()
{
            static int Total_Frame_Number=0;
            Total_Frame_Number++;
            cv::Mat Point_MAT = cv::Mat(PD_Classifier_VEC[0].size(),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(0)); 

   ....//Some Calculation //

        if(Total_Frame_Number==56)
        {
        std::cout<<Point_MAT<<"\n";            //it displays the elements perfectly
        int Nonz = cv::countNonZero(Point_MAT);  //it runs too
        cv::imshow("Point_MAT",Point_MAT);          //here the error appears !!!
        cv::waitKey();
        }
       PD_Classifier_VEC[0].release();
       PD_Classifier_VEC.erase(PD_Classifier_VEC.begin());

}
```

As you can see, the comments provided above the first two lines works fine but when I try to show the image using imshow the program crashes and it displays the corrupted double linked list error !!! what's wrong here?

Why I can't display this image and if the POINT_MAT image is corrupted how the first two lines works fine ?

P.S
If I start the program from j=57, it works fine till it finishes and no error appears so the

```
//some calculation
```

code works fine and I'm sure about it.

I've test many other functions such as threshold, subtract and ... which works on data part of the image and they work fine but when I add a function which work on metadata + data parts the corrupted double linked list appears again !!!

```
cv::subtract(Point_MAT,Point_MAT,temp); //works fine because it only works on data part
Point_MAT.copyTo(Temp_MAT); //gives error cause it works on header part too ...
```

Comment: The obvious suggestion is to remove the "some calculation" part. It should work (without the `release()`) on the code without the calculation, for many more images.

Comment: -1 since you're not providing any code that actually fails. Everything so far (`release()` notwithstanding) works fine. I know, I've tried it.

Comment: Now you know how unproductive it is not to show a **complete, self contained example**. Questions such as yours appear on SO again, and again, and the askers always, uniformly, claim that they *don't* need to provide any other code. They are **always** wrong, and they waste their', and the answerers' time, in doing so.

Comment: yeah I try not to repeat it again ... I learned something important today about how to provide codes in SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the standard C library, and indicates that you've corrupted the heap.

Specifically, you should not call `release()` on a `Cv::mat` unless you have a matching `addref()` in *your own code*. `Cv::mat` behaves like an implicitly-shared value common in Qt (like say `QImage`), you shouldn't worry about managing its reference counts manually.

The obvious suggestion is to remove the "some calculation" part. The code you show *as is* should work (without the `release()`) without the calculation, for many more images.

Convert the code that you show to a separate, single file project, and make sure it runs - because it should. Then the error is limited to your calculations - the fact that it only manifests itself when you do the calculations is a symptom of the problem with calculations.

Perhaps the calculations allocate memory?

The below is a working, self-contained example that demonstrates that the shown code is not only OK, but everything works even if you store a hundred images in memory at once. The images are 2MB in size each.

```
#include <QImage>
#include <QTemporaryFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

std::vector<cv::Mat> PD_Classifier_VEC;

void PD()
{
  cv::Mat Point_MAT = cv::Mat(PD_Classifier_VEC[0].size(),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(0));

  //Some Calculation //

  std::stringstream stream;
  stream<<Point_MAT<<"\n";
  int Nonz = cv::countNonZero(Point_MAT);
  cv::imshow("Point_MAT",Point_MAT);

  PD_Classifier_VEC.erase(PD_Classifier_VEC.begin());
}

int main()
{
  QTemporaryFile file;
  file.setFileTemplate(file.fileTemplate() + ".jpg");

  const int N = 100;
  for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
  {
    file.open();
    QImage img(800, 600, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    img.save(&file);
    file.close();
    QString address = file.fileName();
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(address.toStdString(),0);
    PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(image);
  }
  while (!PD_Classifier_VEC.empty()) PD();
  cv::waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Again, `Cv::mat` is a proper C++ class. When you're done using it, you destruct it. That's what `erase` does. For the moment forget about `addref` and `release` methods, they are only useful in very specific situations when you want to intervene in `mat`'s memory management. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Parsa There's also a possibility that you have huge images and you're running out of heap. How big are your images (in megabytes)?

Comment: between 1 to 2 megabytes at most ..can you tell me how to increase the heap size in qt so I check whether this is the source of the problem or not ?

Comment: so propose anything I could test to see where could I find the source of the problem .. I'm quite skillful in programing ...

Comment: thanks the problem was in the sequence of some opencv functions !! I rewrote them and the problem was solved ...

Comment: @Parsa "I'm quite skillful in programing" That may be, but it seems that you haven't read [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [this](http://www.sscce.org). It applies to debugging big programs, too.

Comment: @Parsa By not providing an sscce, and "rewriting" your "sequence" of "some" opencv functions, I can't be sure that you understand what exactly you did wrong. It's not obvious that you've gained any further understanding by doing the "rewriting". I sincerely hope that you have your code under source control and can compare the working variant to non-working one, and uncover what exactly did you do wrong. Anything less is an imitation of understanding. If you have a source control system but you don't commit often, then you're using it wrong :)

Comment: yeah I agree, right now I'm trying to understand what caused the problem so I could prevent it from happening again ...I'll read sscce and the other link to not repeat this kind of bad question again ...

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is well described in Kuba's answer.

In my case I was passing a `cv::Mat` as parameter to a function to the image. But by the point where the main thread would access that mat, the worker thread which took the image had already deleted it.

The solution was to pass a clone of the mat.

```cpp
    ...
    cv::Mat const img = recordImage();
    myWindow->setImage(img);
} // end of function, img will get deleted
```

```cpp
    ...
    cv::Mat const img = recordImage();
    myWindow->setImage(img.clone());
} // img will get deleted, but the clone will persist
```