# opencv c++ corrupted double-linked list

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, coredump

I'm trying to get the fps from multiple cameras. This is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Load all cameras IP
    map<string, string> camerasIp; //camera ID and Streaming URL
    LoadConfig(&camerasIp);

    //Get FPS of all cameras
    map<string,string>::iterator it_cam;

    while(true)
    {
        for(it_cam = camerasIp.begin(); it_cam != camerasIp.end(); ++it_cam)
        {
            GetCamFps(it_cam->second);
        }

        cout << "" << endl;
    }

    //Send FPS to server
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

This is the GetCamFps method:

```
void GetCamFps(string url)
{
    cout << "VideoCapture" << endl;
    VideoCapture video(url);

    cout << "Get frames" << endl;
    double fps = video.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
    cout <<"Frames: " << fps << endl;

    video.release();
}
```

And this is the exit:

```
VideoCapture
Get frames
Frames: 30
VideoCapture
corrupted double-linked list
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried adding a sleep to let some time between opening one url and another but didn't works. I checked the map and it's correct.

When I comment the two firsts cout in the method it works but after a while it fail again.

Output of gdb with backtrace:

```
Thread 1 "Fps_Monitoring" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff51cc801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff5215897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff5342b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff521c90a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff5340cba "corrupted double-linked list") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff521cac4 in malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7ffff5577c40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4456
#5  0x00007ffff52207d8 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff5577c40 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=1600) at malloc.c:3703
#6  0x00007ffff52214eb in _int_memalign (av=0x7ffff5577c40 <main_arena>, alignment=64, bytes=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4694
#7  0x00007ffff5226fba in _mid_memalign (address=<optimized out>, bytes=1496, alignment=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3314
#8  __posix_memalign (memptr=0x7fffffffdad0, alignment=<optimized out>, size=1496) at malloc.c:5369
#9  0x00007ffff028e7e3 in av_malloc () from /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.56
#10 0x00007ffff06b253b in avformat_alloc_context () from /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.58
#11 0x00007ffff5f8b9a3 in CvCapture_FFMPEG::open(char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
#12 0x00007ffff5f8e9ff in cv::cvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_proxy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
#13 0x00007ffff5f71566 in cv::StaticBackend::createCapture(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
#14 0x00007ffff5f4cc17 in cv::VideoCapture::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
#15 0x00007ffff5f4f595 in cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
#16 0x000055555555f9b3 in GetCamFps(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) ()
#17 0x000055555555d5df in main ()
```

Any idea why the second videocapture doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the bug is here: `LoadConfig(&camerasIp);` or what happens in LoadConfig

Comment: Just read a xml file with the IDs and URLs of each camera, create a pair and add it to the map

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897157/what-does-corrupted-double-linked-list-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897157/what-does-corrupted-double-linked-list-mean)

Comment: There's a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842151/corrupted-double-linked-list-for-opencv-library
Try removing `video.release()` statement, maybe it'll help. The C++ destructor will do all necessary cleanup anyway.

Comment: It's seems the problem is open multiple cameras